# Comparing two object arrays and check if they have common elements

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How can I execute a query in MongoDB that returns _id if `FirstArray` and `SecondArray` has elements in common in "Name" field?

This is the collection structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b8d9e3b2b4e07bff8feed5"),
    "FirstArray" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "A",
            "Something" : "200 ",
        }, 
        {
               "Name" : "GF",
            "Something" : "100 ",
        } 
    ],
    "SecondArray" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "BC",
            "Something" : "200 ",
        }, 
        {
               "Name" : "A",
            "Something" : "100 ",
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

3.6 Update:

Use `$match` with `$expr`. `$expr` allows use of aggregation expressions inside `$match` stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$match":{
    "$expr":{
      "$eq":[
        {"$size":{"$setIntersection":["$FirstArray.Name","$SecondArray.Name"]}},
        0
      ]
    }
  }},
  {"$project":{"_id":1}}
])
```

Old version:

You can try `$redact` with `$setIntersection` for your query.

`$setIntersection` to compare the `FirstArray`s `Name`s with `SecondArray`s `Name`s and return array of common names documents followed by `$size` and `$redact` and compare result with `0` to keep and else remove the document.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  [{
    $redact: {
      $cond: {
        if: {
          $eq: [{
            $size: {
              $setIntersection: ["$FirstArray.Name", "$SecondArray.Name"]
            }
          }, 0]
        },
        then: "$$KEEP",
        else: "$$PRUNE"
      }
    }
  }, {
    $project: {
      _id: 1
    }
  }]
)
```