# How do I query in an array of objects in mongodb

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, javascript-objects

I have a db object looking like this:

```
{
   user_name: 'string',
   skills: [ 
       { skill: 'skill1', lvl: 3 } 
   ],
   wantsToLearn: [ 
       {skill: 'skill2' } 
   ]
}
```

I want to make a query wherein I find all users with a wantToLearn skill matching with one pf my input user's skill (regardless of lvl) AND vice versa. Basically, I want to be able to find all users with a match between a skill and something they want to learn.

I have looked at the mongodb documentation and am still a bit clueless on how to do this the best way. I am new to databases in general except for some sql.

Any pointers would be very appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two object arrays and check if they have common elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42583967/comparing-two-object-arrays-and-check-if-they-have-common-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find all users matching your given skill, all you have to do is :

`db.getCollection('yourCollection').find({"wantsToLearn.skill": "skill2" })`

That's the way you query subdocuments in MongoDB, even in arrays