# MongoDB - compare fields of array objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to find all documents where an element of an array in that document matches a condition of it's fields:

```
{
  doc_id: 0,
  array_field: [
    { id: 0, min: 1, max: 2 },
    { id: 1, min: 1, max: 1 },
    ...
  ]
}
...
```

I need all documents where any object in `array_field` has a `max != min`.

I've been using `$elemMatch` to query the array elements (which works fine by itself), but I can't seem to make it work with an `$expr`:

```
{
  array_field: {
    $elemMatch: {
        $expr: { $ne: [ "$min", "$max" ]}
    }
  }
}
```

How do I correctly compare the fields within the array object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use aggregation operators with query operators. You can use `$setDifference` to compare min with max array and return if there are elements in the min array which are not in max array.

Use `$expr` with `$setDifference`. `$expr` allows use of aggregation expressions in the regular find query.

Something like

```
db.collection.find({
    "$expr":{
      "$ne":[
        {"$size":{"$setDifference":["$array_field.min","$$array_field.max"]}},
        0
      ]
    }
  }
)
```

You can also look at here to return when there is matching elements in arrays.

[Comparing two object arrays and check if they have common elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42583967/comparing-two-object-arrays-and-check-if-they-have-common-elements/42584543#42584543)

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{"$match":{
"$expr":{
  "$eq":[
    {"$size":{"$setIntersection":["$min","$max"]}},
    0
  ]
}
}},
    {"$project":{"_id":1}}
])
```

$setIntersection to compare the FirstArrays Names with SecondArrays Names and return array of common names documents followed by $size and $redact and compare result with 0 to keep and else remove the document.